# JSON element added not showing

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I am using express.js to develop an API. I have a json object returned by mongoose and I need to add en element to each element in the result.docs.

I am doing this as follows:

```
for(a in result.docs)
    { 
       result.docs[a].links={
            "test":'test',
            "test": 'test', 
            "test": 'test' 
        };

    }
```

After doing so I am returning the result object, however the links are not added. On the other hand if I write

```
console.log(result.docs[1].links);
```

the object is shown properly.

Any ideas please?

Thanks

Comment: the properties have the same name ...? is `result.docs` an array or an object?

Comment: no the properties have different names, I just wrote test to remove the data. result.docs is an array of objects

Comment: `console.log(result.docs[1].links);` if you are able to do that then they are added, so what do you mean by _"however the links are not added"_ what is making you think they are not added

Comment: when I do console.log(result) or console.log(result.docs[1]) the links element is not shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you're working with a mongoose Document instance instead of a plain object, in that case you could use the `toObject` method to get a plain object, so the implementation could be:

```
var objs = [];

for(var a in result.docs) {
   var obj = result.docs[a].toObject();
   obj.links = {
        "test":'test',
        "test": 'test', 
        "test": 'test' 
    };       
   objs.push(obj);
}

// Do something with objs
```

[toObject Documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject)

Comment: Thanks, for some weird reason this worked for some elements found in the docs array. This was not added to the first few elements. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh I get it now, each object is being pushed in docs again, so basically I have 2 copies of the same element- the original one and the one with the links. I need to empty the docs element before pushing the objs. Thanks very much

Comment: Sorry, I forget to rename some variables, I updated the code again

Answer (score 0):

So, try this code:

```
for each (var a in result.docs){
    a.links = { //put your data
    };
}
```

Comment: Also [for each ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in) is depreciated and only available in firefox